# Efficient way to perform iterative subtraction and division operations on pandas columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a following dataframe-

```
      A    B   C  Result
 0  232  120   9      91
 1  243  546   1      12
 2   12  120   5      53
```

I want to perform the operation of the following kind-

```
      A    B   C  Result   A-B/A+B   A-C/A+C   B-C/B+C
  0 232  120   9      91  0.318182  0.925311  0.860465
  1 243  546   1      12 -0.384030  0.991803  0.996344
  2  12  120   5      53 -0.818182  0.411765  0.920000
```

which I am doing using

```
 df['A-B/A+B']=(df['A']-df['B'])/(df['A']+df['B'])
 df['A-C/A+C']=(df['A']-df['C'])/(df['A']+df['C'])
 df['B-C/B+C']=(df['B']-df['C'])/(df['B']+df['C'])
```

which I believe is a very crude and ugly way to do.
How to do it in a more correct way?

Comment: You're already doing it in a correct and (IMHO) best way.

Comment: But if we increase the no. of columns then don't you think it would become a bit inefficient

Comment: It's efficient (vectorised) and self-explanatory. What would you envision as "pretty"?

Comment: @LukaszTracewski I was more searching for a loop kind of method in case no. of columns increases.

Comment: Now I got it. @YOLO got it nice.

Comment: You don't want a loop kind of method, it will be slower. The vectorised method you already have is most efficient, and the pandaic way of doing it. It doesn't matter how many columns you have, you can do `df['A']+df['B']+df['C']+df['D']+...`

Comment: @matthiash What are your views on the solution by yolo as I believe it is vectorized and is just looping the column process

Comment: Ok, now I also understand what you're trying to achieve. I thought you wanted to loop over the rows, which would be a bad idea. Yolo's solution seems good to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
# take columns in a list except the last column
colnames = df.columns.tolist()[:-1]

# compute 
for i, c in enumerate(colnames):
    if i != len(colnames):
        for k in range(i+1, len(colnames)):
            df[c + '_' + colnames[k]] = (df[c] - df[colnames[k]]) / (df[c] + df[colnames[k]])

# check result
print(df)

     A    B  C  Result       A_B       A_C       B_C
0  232  120  9      91  0.318182  0.925311  0.860465
1  243  546  1      12 -0.384030  0.991803  0.996344
2   12  120  5      53 -0.818182  0.411765  0.920000
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect case to use [`DataFrame.eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html#pandas.DataFrame.eval):

```
cols = ['A-B/A+B','A-C/A+C','B-C/B+C']
x = pd.DataFrame([df.eval(col).values for col in cols], columns=cols)
df.assign(**x)

    A    B   C    Result  A-B/A+B     A-C/A+C     B-C/B+C
0  232  120  9      91  351.482759  786.753086  122.000000
1  243  546  1      12  240.961207  243.995885   16.583333
2   12  120  5      53  128.925000  546.998168  124.958333
```

The advantage of this method respect to the other solution, is that it does  not depend on the order of the operation sings that appear as column names, but rather as mentioned in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html#pandas.DataFrame.eval) it is used to:

> Evaluate a string describing operations on DataFrame columns.